Suggestion for catching a flight with short layover in Amsterdam
I am an Indian citizen (Indian Passport) who is travelling Business class from Mumbai, India to New York, US with a stopover in Amsterdam, Netherlands
My flight is DL9495 2:25 am Mumbai to 7:45 am Amsterdam and then DL0047 8:55 am Amsterdam to 11:35 am New York.
It’s a very short layover, moreover I will be traveling with my wife who is an Indian citizen and an infant who is an American citizen. My wife and I both have Advance Parole card from US (instead of visa; as our Green card is in progress)
Tickets have been booked through Priceline and have the same PNR.

The answers have not explicitly stated so, but since you are booked on a single ticket, in AMS you will not go through passport control and will not have to do anything with your checked bags which will be sent to the next flight automatically. It’s really just a matter of deplane-security-go to the right gate.

My experience from Schiphol transfers would be to start your training for a marathon before flying.

That is indeed a close connection with an infant.

Make sure you get all boarding passes in Mumbai. Try online check in as well: you do NOT want to stop by a transfer desk in AMS.
Most likely you will be arriving at the F gates and departing from the D gates. Familiarize yourself with the airport layout and make sure you are familiar with the way
Shortly before the departure, check gates for these flight numbers that were used the last few days. Can simple Google "DL9495 status" Chances are your gate will be in the same area
Since you are flying business you will be in the front of the plane and are first to disembark. However, if you have a stroller you might be asked to drop it the airplane door in Mumbai. In this case you will have to wait at the airplane door in AMS until they have unloaded it. If that's the case, let the staff in Mumbai know that you will need the stroller quickly. Not bringing  a stroller could help here.
You can let the flight attendants know that you have a tight connection and they may let get you out of the plane first.
Since you are coming from India, there is a good chance you will be routed through transfer security. Make sure you go to the priority or special assistance line and have all the stuff that needs to come out available. Ask any staff that directs you if they can move you to the front of line (sometimes they will with a stroller).
Make sure you minimize the required time on the ground. Do feeding and diaper changes maybe an hour or so before landing. Go to the bathroom yourself.
Quite likely there is going to be another doc check for US bound flights either at the gate or at the entrance to the terminal. Make sure you head for the priority or special assistance lane if they have any.

Chances are you will be fine. If things are "normal" that's perfectly doable. In this case, it's also helpful if you have checked luggage. Luggage will most likely travel faster than you and if you are not at the departure gate before closing time, they cannot leave without unloading you luggage first, which buys you some extra time.
In case you do miss it (by no fault of your own). DL/KLM will rebook you on the next available flight. Since yours is the first one out, there are likely to be 3 more that day although getting 3 business class seats maybe a challange.

I don’t know what DL/KLM’s policies are in AMS, but it’s likely they will have staff waiting for you at the gate (of the first flight), especially if the incoming flight is delayed, to escort you to the next flight as quickly as possible. Unless they already rebooked you to a later flight (if incoming is late).

@jcaron I have had shorter connections, with an exit border check, when they didn't bother. I have actually been on a AF or KLM flight to Schiphol where flight attendants did prioritize people with very short connections, move them closer to the exit and give them special instructions but most connections didn't make the cut. I would be surprised if they would do anything for a 70 minute connection, unless the incoming flight is delayed. Only reason I could see them doing that is if the connection is especially popular and they want to avoid having to take care of a dozen people at once.

@jcaron: I don't think there is any predictable behavior. I've seen planes being held for 30+ minutes, I've had a gate agent giving away my seat BEFORE gate closing time since "they didn't think I would make it" (I did). In another case a gate agent closed the gate a bit early stranding six passengers that they already knew where in the terminal on their way. Instead of waiting maybe 2 more minutes they chose to close early which required putting 6 passengers up over night at significant cost to the airline. I don't see any logic here.

@Hilmar Oh, I'm not going to pretend there's any form of logic! There are sometimes vague policies, but (a) they can be complex, depending on the airline, the airport, the connection time, the type of connection (DD/ID/DI/II), the duration and/or frequency of the next flight, the reason for the delay, the status of the passenger, the class of travel, and the phase of the moon, (b) they are not necessarily followed consistently. But it may happen that they escort you (this is probably a lore more frequent in airports in Asia). "Likely" was probably too strong. "Possible" is more realistic.

@Relaxed I was once ferried in a car from an arriving flight to a departing flight -- along with my travel companion and one or two others -- to make a tight connection.  This was in Vienna, and the destination was Sarajevo -- had we missed the connection, they'd have had to spend money on hotels in addition to the compensation. There is much more capacity between Amsterdam and New York than there is between Vienna and Sarajevo. It's quite likely that airlines take this into account when deciding which short connections to prioritize for assistance.

@phoog Sure, anything is possible, I have my own stories, at least an escort waiting at the door to shuffle you through security and border control (it was also on a ticket to a somewhat off-the-beaten path destination with Austrian, incidentally). Only question is whether they would bother in this particular case and my guess is not at Schiphol and not for a 70 minute connection (and I have actually recently been through Schiphol for a shorter connection to a once-a-day intercontinental flight very recently).

Just for context: We are talking about an airport that's half under construction, was a complete disaster two years ago and apparently still understaffed.

@Relaxed As it's my home airport, and my partner flies a lot, I can comment here - a lot of the construction and staffing problems have vanished in the last year. Yes, still major construction works, but they're not affecting much of the infrastructure OP will have to travel through. Was a nightmare 2 years ago, though. Now our construction woes have moved to the Eurostar :P

Will second user183304's comment, and have two more: Dutch society, by and large, is very child friendly - ask for help on the flight because of moving the newborn quickly, and the flight attendants will be way more likely to help. And be friendly but with a specific request - Dutch directness is a thing. (By this, I mean saying something like "I worry about making the next flight" is likely to be met with "oh, yes, you should worry, that is a very short connection", whereas "Is it possible to get off quickly, so we can make our connection" is more likely to get a useful response

@lupe There was still some significant construction between piers C and D (right where the transfer border check is) a couple of weeks ago. Same thing for staffing (see the article I linked to). But yeah not as catastrophic as two years ago, which is a low bar to clear.

@user183304: I once at Schiphol witnessed a lady in the VIP security queue without the proper qualifications being asked to leave the queue. She shouted something along the lines of "do you know who I am?", which made zero impression and then she was moved to the back of the "commoners" queue, to great amusement of everyone.

There's not much you can do at this point to increase your chances of making the connection beyond the following:

be prepared to move as quickly as possible when you arrive in Amsterdam; the lighter your cabin bags, the more quickly you'll be able to move.

ask the cabin crew of your flight to Amsterdam whether you will have any assistance making the connection -- if the time is short, especially if the flight is delayed, some airlines will have staff waiting to meet you and help expedite your transfer.  Consider approaching the cabin crew during a part of the flight when they aren't too busy, for example, a couple of minutes after they've collected the trash after meal service.

if the cabin crew can't help, look for staff at the arrival gate.

don't assume that the gate on your boarding pass is correct -- it might easily have been changed while you were in the air.  The first thing you should do if no staff are available to help is to find a departures monitor and confirm the gate.

remember that it will become difficult or impossible to use the plane's bathrooms during the last 20 to 30 minutes of the flight.  Around an hour before arrival, do that.  At this point, you can also organize your carry-on luggage if necessary (to repack it, mainly), so you can leave the plane efficiently and proceed to your next flight without having to stop.


Finally, for your own peace of mind

don't worry too much about missing the flight.  It's a distinct possibility.  If you do miss it, you'll be rebooked; at that hour you're quite likely to be rebooked later on the same day.


I agree with the other answers, they have valuable tips to save time. However, no one mention that if you or your party have reduced mobility you could also request assistance from the airline: https://www.klm.de/en/information/assistance-health/mobility-assistance they can arrange a transport (likely one of those minibuses) from one gate to the other at the airport. From the wording of the link one might think that this service is only for severely disabled people, but anyone that has trouble making a short connection can ask for it. Likely they might get wheelchairs ready for you at check in. You should just be honest with them and explain that you don't need assistance boarding at origin, neither to get out at the destination, but you need help in order to make the connection in Amsterdam.
I have middle aged friends who only ask mobility assistance for short layovers.

The carts go faster than an average walker and this should help you skip the line at security but it could be a mixed blessing overall: People who need assistance are usually invited to wait in the plane for everybody else to have left so that the airport staff can pick them up. Even if you make it out on your own, if someone else in the plane needs assistance and there is only one cart for everybody, you might have to wait for them to go out. Because of all this, the page you linked to actually recommends longer connection times (more than 90 minutes) when using this service.

90 minutes is just a recommendation. In my experience airlines make accommodations for short layovers.
